# Is this the most efficient algorithm to calculate the cross product of two sets of numbers?

Tags: f#, cartesian-product

This question has already been asked for more general contexts. However, in this specific context:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

#time
// s1 and s2 are both two ordered sets of numbers
// i.e. the both s1 and s2 do not contain duplicates
let inline calcSeq op (s1: 'a list) (s2: 'a list) =
    let m = new HashSet<'a>()

    for x1 in s1 do
        for x2 in s2 do
            m.Add(x1 |> op <| x2) |> ignore
    m
    |> Seq.toList

let inline multLists s1 s2  = calcSeq (*) s1 s2
let inline divLists s1 s2   = calcSeq (/) s1 s2
let inline sumLists s1 s2   = calcSeq (+) s1 s2
let inline subtrLists s1 s2 = calcSeq (-) s1 s2
```

Is this the most efficient way to calculate the set of numbers as a result of the cross product of two sets of numbers.

Obviously the performance is O(s1 |> Seq.lenght, s2 |> Seq.length). So the performance is like:

```
> multLists [1..5] [1..10];;
Real: 00:00:00.002, CPU: 00:00:00.015, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
val it : int list =
  [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 12; 14; 16; 18; 20; 15; 21; 24; 27; 30; 28;
   32; 36; 40; 25; 35; 45; 50]
> multLists [1..1000] [1..5000];;
Real: 00:00:02.052, CPU: 00:00:02.121, GC gen0: 100, gen1: 9, gen2: 1
val it : int list =
  [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; 20; 21;
   22; 23; 24; 25; 26; 27; 28; 29; 30; 31; 32; 33; 34; 35; 36; 37; 38; 39; 40;
   41; 42; 43; 44; 45; 46; 47; 48; 49; 50; 51; 52; 53; 54; 55; 56; 57; 58; 59;
   60; 61; 62; 63; 64; 65; 66; 67; 68; 69; 70; 71; 72; 73; 74; 75; 76; 77; 78;
   79; 80; 81; 82; 83; 84; 85; 86; 87; 88; 89; 90; 91; 92; 93; 94; 95; 96; 97;
   98; 99; 100; ...]
```

But maybe there are some clever tricks I can do to make this faster?

Note, for example, that if you multLists [1..2] [1..3] you get [1;2;3;4;6], skipping 5, while multiplying [1..1000] with [1..5000] gives at least a list of [1..100] without skipping any. However, there will be duplicates further on.

P.m. If you care to down vote this question, please take some time to explain, I might learn something.

Comment: This isn't quite a cartesian product.  The cartesian product would return `(1,1)::(1,2)::(1,3)::...`

Comment: @JohnPalmer. I get that, how do you propose to call this?

Comment: sorry, missed that.  In terms of performance I think that avoiding the `ResizeArray` would be faster.  Also, I think you could probably beat the `HashSet` for performance by utilising the fact that the input data is sorted, but it would get very complicated.

Comment: Also `x1 |> op <| x2` intuitively sounds like a worse idea than plain `op x1 x2`

Comment: I would also drop the `ResizeArray` - just iterate over the input lists. I don't think you can do any clever optimizations without knowing anything about the operation (here, even the fact that the inputs are sorted does not help much).

Comment: Thanks, I dropped the resize array, but that doesn't make any difference, other than it just didn't make sense. The bottleneck for the performance seems to be the filtering of duplicates. Just doing the calculation (with a resize array, because than it does make a difference) is way faster, but than you have duplicates...

Comment: @scrwtp, I did that because op is an infix operator.

Comment: @TomasPetricek, Well in fact you do know the operators, they are shown below, so you could take that into account to do the optimisation.

Comment: @scrwtp using `(op x1 x2)` is indeed faster.

Comment: @Mau, did some measurements, but doesn't seem to really matter. Certainly not the performance bottleneck.

Comment: @halcwb: obviously not a bottleneck, that's why it's a comment not an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well as it has been posted before, basically this will have an O(n*m) performance, so really bad! Just having hanging this in my code can get me into trouble.

However, as has been stated this is a particular use case scenario. What I tried to achieve was to come up with a set of possible answers to the cross product of performing a calculation between two sets of numbers. So, actually, I did not need ALL the answers, just a reasonable list of options.

For my use case, when you prescribe something 3 or 4 times a day and you can pick between 1 and 5 tablets per time, you'll get the following range of possibilities to pick from to get the daily total: multiplyLists [3;4] [1..5] = [3; 6; 9; 12; 15; 4; 8; 16; 20]. In reality its a bit more complicated than that, but it boils down to this principle. So, I want to prevent the user from deciding that 5 tablets per day was a viable option given the restrictions.

So, the solution was trivial (just did not realise it for a long time;-():

```
let maximize n (set: list<_>) =
    let max = set.Length
    if n >= max then set
    else
        let set = set |> Seq.sort
        let nth = max / (n - 1)
        let i = ref 0
        [ for x in set do
            if !i % nth = 0 then
                yield x 
            i := !i + 1 ]


let inline calcSeq op (s1: 'a list) (s2: 'a list) =
    let m = new HashSet<'a>()
    let s1 = s1 |> maximize 100
    let s2 = s2 |> maximize 100
    for x1 in s1 do
        for x2 in s2 do
            m.Add(op x1 x2) |> ignore
    m
    |> Seq.toList

let inline multLists s1 s2  = calcSeq (*) s1 s2
let inline divLists s1 s2   = calcSeq (/) s1 s2
let inline sumLists s1 s2   = calcSeq (+) s1 s2
let inline subtrLists s1 s2 = calcSeq (-) s1 s2
```